# Rails Ubuntu/passenger/capistrano app assets not deploying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, capistrano, asset-pipeline

None of my assets are updating with changes anymore. I'm using the same settings as I was, but now when I make a change to any of my '.html.erb' files or '.scss' files, they aren't showing up when I add them to git and deploy them with capistrano. Any idea what might be happening with this?

Maybe I should reinstall everything on the remote server I'm deploying to?

I'm using:
Rails 4.2.5.1
ruby 2.2.3p173

production.rb:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like
  # NGINX, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
  #config.serve_static_files = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  #config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true
end
```

I also use `RAILS_ENV=production rake asssets:precompile` to compile my assets before deploying them.

Comment: try changing config.assets.compile to true and 
config.assets.precompile =  [' *.js', ' *.scss', '*.css']

Comment: need an asterisk in front of .js and .css but stack isn't reading those for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

you could try precompiling your assets locally, committing and then deploying again.

```
rake assets:precompile
```

It's not the best practice, but I've done it before when I needed to. Also check the stack trace during deployment. Typically there's an error somewhere in your css or js that is keeping your assets from compiling.

Comment: I've tried the rake assets:precompile without the rails_env=production. But run into the same problems. I'll check my trace and see if I'm getting any errors from the assets during compile. Thanks. @toddmetheny

Comment: When I run locally, I keep getting:
`App 12242 stderr: autoprefixer: /Users/coreyvincent/Desktop/Applications/RailsApp/app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss:38487:3: Gradient has outdated direction syntax. New syntax is like 'to left' instead of 'right'.`
Whatever that means...? @toddmetheny

Comment: yeah--that means you have an error in your scss that is keeping your assets from compiling. you'll need to find and debug that error.

Comment: I did end up fixing those, and now everything is deploying again and the app runs fine locally. But on the server I'm deploying to, none of the styles are showing up now. Completely gone. :( @toddmetheny